# USB debugging on raspberry pi 4(8 GB RAM model) running with lineage OS 18.1(Android 11)

Tags: usb, android

I am currently working with lineage os 18.1 running on a raspberry pi 4(8GB RAM model) board. I need to look into the logs of the lineage os running on the Rpi board. For that, I need to work with ADB(Android Debug Bridge ) to view the logs on the RPi board. But, that requires USB debugging to be enabled. As Rpi4 doesn't have extra micro USB/USB-C to work with USB debugging. I tried getting the logs over wifi to my laptop. I tried all the ways in which I can get the logs over wifi too like wireless debugging, pairing.

adb connect ip-address of raspberry pi:port -- To connect over wifi

./adb pair ip-adress of raspberry pi:port   -- using wireless pairing

With wifi, I was able to connect to my raspberry pi but the device status is shown as **offline**. I have seen that for configuring the ADB with the device over wifi, we need to connect the device to a laptop/PC over USB to make it work but unfortunately, Rpi doesn't have MicroUSB/USB-C to connect to my laptop. Is there any other way I can access the logs of raspberry pi 4 without USB? Any app suggestions for local ADB shell access(without root) are most welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 2 options

1. enable WIFI debugging by enabling developer options when you click multiple times on the About tablet->Build number
2. enable USB debugging by plug the USB-C into your computer not into power adapter if USB debugging still not working enable developer (About tablet->Build number) then USB debugging

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).